# If a telescope detects death of a star which is 1 million light years away today, doesn't that mean it's dead 1 million years ago?

Tags: nasa, space-telescope, stars

I'm guessing as if its an optical reflecting telescope. How in general does NASA and other research centres detect far away bodies? What telescopes do they use, and in general, wouldn't the event be over before we'd discovered it?

Comment: This really belongs on [Astronomy.SE], but briefly: why do you suppose the event is *not* over before we discover it?

Comment: Shah - everything we see has already happened. The only difference is distance, which correlates very well with time. So yes, every star we see die, whether through optical or radio telescope, actually died a long time ago.

Comment: @NathanTuggy 's suggestion is good - you can also post your question in Astronomy Stackexchange, or even look to see if it's been asked there before. Very loosly: *Space Exploration* Stackexchange is more about the exploration of things a little closer to home, while *Astronomy* Stackexchange is more about studying things far away. While there is plenty of overlap, I think a million light years falls into the "*far away*" category.

Comment: Right, never realised there's an Astronomy section! It is like you have a music section and a songs section. :D

Comment: @Shah Abaz Khan: Actually that's more apt than you might think, since a songs section pretty much limits you to the ghetto of popular "music", while a music section would include symphonies, concertos, &c.  There might not be much overlap :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that event was *roughly* 1mln years ago.

At scales of "merely" a million light years, the inaccuracy would be of order of 10 days. On distances of billions of light years the inaccuracy can climb considerably due to space expansion - an event we have observed today, that ocurred a couple billion years ago, occurred a considerably shorter time ago than its distance in light years would indicate. After all, the radius of the observable universe is 46.5 billion light years but the age of the universe is 13.82 billion years.

Various astronomical institutes worldwide mostly use radiotelescopes and telescopes of infrared and higher spectra. Due to the Red Shift phenomenon (caused by space expansion) they are more useful at picking radiation of distant objects than visible spectrum ones. And yes, at these distances they observe events that are long long past.

Comment: This is a tough one! We use lightyears not just because meters would have too many zeros. Because space is expanding, as well as sculpted by the gravity of everything in it, about the only sensible way to talk about distance is the travel time of light. Inaccuracies can also come from the fact that space isn't a perfect vacuum and different wavelengths (and particles) take different times to get here due to different interactions with the charged particles [(dispersion)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_radio_burst#Further_developments)and even other photons in space.

Comment: The use of SI-prefixes and meters is possible for distances of lightyears too, one lightyears is 9.46 Petameters and a million lightyears  9.46 Zettameters. For a billion lightyears, Yottameters may be used.